# How do i move an object on the screen using the mousex and mousey coordinates in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to move the green object called char relative to the mouse x and mouse y coordinates but I don't know how. Can anyone help me? In case you are wondering i am trying to make a version of single player agario.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from random import uniform, randrange
import time
#left,top,right,bottom

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk,width=600,height=600)
canvas.pack()

pointcount = 0

char = canvas.create_oval(400,400,440,440,fill="green")
pos1 = canvas.coords(char)
x = canvas.canvasx()
y = canvas.canvasy()
class Ball:#ball characteristics#
    def __init__(self,color,size):
        self.shape = canvas.create_oval(10,10,50,50,fill=color)
        self.xspeed = randrange(-5,7)
        self.yspeed = randrange(-5,7) 
    def move(self):#ball animation#
        global pointcount
        canvas.move(self.shape,self.xspeed,self.yspeed)
        pos = canvas.coords(self.shape)
        if pos[0] <= 0 or pos[2] >= 600:#if ball hits the wall#
            self.xspeed = -self.xspeed
        if pos[1] <= 0 or pos[3] >= 600:
            self.yspeed = -self.yspeed
        left_var = abs(pos[0] - pos1[0])
        top_var = abs(pos[1] - pos1[1])
        if left_var == 0 and top_var == 0:
            pointcount = pointcount + 1
            print(pointcount)


colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow","purple","orange"]
balls = []

for i in range(10):
    balls.append(Ball(random.choice(colors),50))

while True:
    for ball in balls:
        ball.move()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

To move the green circle with the mouse, you need to bind the position of the circle to mouse motion event. Here is an example where the circle is always centered on the mouse when the mouse is in the canvas:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

char = canvas.create_oval(400,400,440,440,fill="green")

def follow_mouse(event):
    """ the center of char follows the mouse """
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    canvas.coords(char, x - 20, y - 20, x + 20, y + 20)

# bind follow_mouse function to mouse motion events
canvas.bind('<Motion>', follow_mouse)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but whenever I try to incorporate it into my original program it doesn't work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: I put the `def follow_mouse...` and the `canvas.bind` between the for loop and the while loop (not inside them) in your code and it works (I add to remove the `x/y = canvas.canvasx/y()` that returns an error and is not used in your code snippet.