# How to move a button on a canvas tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi I want to be able to move a lightbulb that has a button on it around the screen. I have tried to make the button change the lightbulb from white to yellow to look like it has been turned on and off. My program just adds the lightbulb to the canvas but you can't move it or change the colour without errors coming up. I also want to add more than one lightbulb on the canvas, which can move on its own.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.grid()

canvas=Canvas(root,height=600,width=600)
canvas.grid()

input_id=0

def addInputs():
   global input_id
   input_id+=1
   input_tag="input-%s"%input_id
   tags=("input",input_tag)
   canvas.create_oval(200,200,250,250,fill="WHITE",width=5,tag=tags)
   canvas.create_rectangle(210,245,237,275,fill="LIGHTGREY",width=5,tag=tags)
   onBtn=Button(root,text="On/Off",command=lambda:inputStatusOn())
   onBtn.place(x=200,y=212)
   canvas.tag_bind(input_tag,onBtn,"<B1-Motion>", lambda event,tag=input_tag:moveInput(event,tag,onBtn))

def inputStatusOn():
   global input_id
   input_id+=1
   input_tag="input-%s"%input_id
   tags=("input",input_tag)
   canvas.delete("input")
   canvas.create_oval(200,200,250,250,fill="YELLOW",width=5,tag=tags)
   canvas.create_rectangle(210,245,237,275,fill="LIGHTGREY",width=5,tag=tags)
   onBtn=Button(root,text="On/Off",command=lambda:inputStatusOff(),tag=tags)
   onBtn.place(x=200,y=212)
   canvas.tag_bind(input_tag,onBtn,"<B1-Motion>", lambda event,tag=input_tag:moveInput(event,tag,onBtn))

def inputStatusOff():
   global input_id
   input_id+=1
   input_tag="input-%s"%input_id
   tags=("input",input_tag)
   canvas.delete("input")
   canvas.create_oval(200,200,250,250,fill="WHITE",width=5,tag=tags)
   canvas.create_rectangle(210,245,237,275,fill="LIGHTGREY",width=5,tag=tags)
   onBtn=Button(root,text="On/Off",command=lambda:inputStatusOn(),tag=tags)
   onBtn.place(x=200,y=212)
   canvas.tag_bind(input_tag,onBtn,"<B1-Motion>", lambda event,tag=input_tag:moveInput(event,tag,onBtn))




def moveInput(event, tag,onBtn):
   x=event.x
   y=event.y
   coords=canvas.coords(tag,onBtn)
   movex=x-coords[0]
   movey=y-coords[1]
   canvas.move(tag,onBtn, movex, movey)

btn=Button(root,text="Add Input",command=lambda:addInputs())
btn.place(x=100,y=100)
```

Comment: Your question is not precise enough, please give us the errors and traceback. And I advise you to take a look at the documentation (e.g. http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_oval.html), the `create_oval` option is `tags` not `tag` and a `Button` does not have a `tag` option.

Comment: You can take a look at the following questions about moving a item around a canvas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067129/trying-to-make-an-object-move-in-a-grid-with-tkinter-through-player-inputs/41078251#41078251, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603194/how-do-i-move-an-object-on-the-screen-using-the-mousex-and-mousey-coordinates-in/41609864#41609864.